# What is meant exactly, by having a 'raw' singing voice?

Tags: voice, voice-training

I have recently undergone my first singing lesson. I was petrified, but came out of it very happy indeed. It was an odd experience; couldn't help but feel like I had accomplished something great. Almost the same feeling as coming off stage, never mind...

**Anyway:**

On the way out of the door, my teacher commented:

*"I like how roar you voice is, we can use that",* only I never asked her what she meant by that. Me personally, I have never heard that in that extent.

What does having a 'raw' voice mean?

Answer (score 1):

A 'raw' voice is basically an unrefined voice, though I don't mean 'unrefined' in a pejorative sense. Rather it sounds like your voice isn't smooth, but has a sort of inherent grit to the tonality. I'm thinking of Joe Cocker's singing voice, with an inherent barky delivery that translates into power, pathos, aggression (etc) when singing.

Answer (score 1):

It means whatever the teacher intended it to mean.

In some contexts a 'raw' voice might mean a strained one, even so far as indicating injury to the throat etc.

But in this context, that of a teacher giving encouragement, it might mean you possess the 'raw materials' of a voice.  Un-refined, but a workable basis.  That's good!

I suggest you don't over-analyse it!